# How to properly indent (align) overflown row`s label ? - (Ant Design Table, Tree Data)

Tags: css, reactjs, web, frontend, antd

I am building a custom component where I am using the table component provided by Ant Design. For most of the parts, everything works as expected, however, there is a "tiny" issue.

I am using the "tree-data" (i.e. nested JSON) data to populate the **Table** component. Due to the fixed column size (which is a requirement) it has been noted during QA that the **row`s label is not properly indented** if it overflows (i.e. starts on a new row).

So my question is, how can indent the label such that when the label starts on a new line it starts from the initial indentation like this:
[image]

The **GOAL** would be to have the label "squeezed" within the green-dashed container.

On **[THIS LINK](https://codesandbox.io/embed/tree-data-antd-4-21-4-forked-gb3bf0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)** you can find a demo (the same as the one in ant design documentation with minor changes) which replicates the issue I am working on.

1. open the link
2. expand the first row (i.e. John Brown sr.) as it is expanded in the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply display 'flex' to the column

```
// index.css
.name-column {
  display: flex;
}

// demo.js
// column
...
...
...
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      className: 'name-column'
    },
...
...
...
```